# IP cameras and servers

Tags: video

Has anyone set up an IP camera system before. I am looking for some reasonable cameras some for use outside and some for use inside. I would also like to know if there are any server/(networked storage) type box thingys that dont require me to buy another dedicated server.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used both Axis and Linksys IP cameras before.  They seem to be fine.  Biggest thing is to find the software you want, then find cameras that are compatible with it.